# Elastic beanstalk with Docker Volumes pointing to files

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Tomcat docker container and want to deploy my webapp on it with Elasticbeanstalk.

With plain docker I don't add my war file to the container but reference to it via the -v flag like:

```
docker run --rm -v data/myfile.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/myFile.war
```

This allows me to reference directly to my war file. I have pushed my image to my docker-hub repo.
Within my Dockerrun.aws.json I want to do the ref of the war file. I know there is the option to do something like:

```
  "Volumes": [
{
  "HostDirectory": "/data",
  "ContainerDirectory": "/data"
}]
```

But that leaves me with the question where is my war file on the Host directory?! 
My workflow is that I package these files:

- Dockerrun.aws.json
- war file

and upload them to aws. But I don't know where the zip file gets extracted on the ec2 instance. Therefore I have no idea how I should reference the volumes to.
Basically I want to do something like this:

```
  "Volumes": [
    {
      "HostDirectory": "?/myFile.war",
      "ContainerDirectory": "/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war"
    }]
```

The ? is basically the part I don't know about

I'm using the web UI. I can upload the zip file that has the Dockerrun.aws.json and the war file. But what do I declare within the Volumes part within the Dockerrun.aws.json
I don't know where aws is extracting my war file I want to do something like:

I could not find anything within the aws documentation. Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file should be in `/var/app/current/`. You can ssh to the instance to verify.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it will help you http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-files

```
files:
  "/data/myfile" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    source: http://foo.bar/myfile
```

&

```
"Volumes": [
    {
      "HostDirectory": "/data/myfile",
      "ContainerDirectory": "/data/myfile"
    }]
```

Comment: Hi, thx for your input. That sounds more like a workaround for me. I already upload a zip file to beanstalk which should contain all dependencies and configuration that are deployed..